# Handling multi line data with double quote in Spark-2.2.0 while reading csv

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Trying to read CSV data into a dataframe in Spark-2.2.0. The cell with the data has multi-line text and the first line has few words in double quotes. Below is the code used. Tried many options but nothing really worked.

```
df = (sqlContext.read
.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("header", "true")
.option("inferSchema","true")
.option("multiLine","true")
.option("quoteMode","ALL")
.option("mode","PERMISSIVE")
.option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace","true")
.option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace","true")
.option("parserLib","UNIVOCITY")
.load("C:/Desktop/testing.csv"))
```

This is the data we are trying to read from the file. First cell has data in three lines.

Input data:

```
+----------------------------------------+------------------------+
|                                    text|                    time|
+----------------------------------------+------------------------+
|#Word #This "are acting though."        | 08-11-2016  05:47:00   |
|This is the                             |                        |
|Not so.                                 |                        |
+----------------------------------------+------------------------+
|I'm not sure if I have any left         | 08-11-2016  05:48:00   |
+----------------------------------------+------------------------+
|bob day is an honest  person            | 08-11-2016  05:49:00   |
|"a loss to the senate"                  |                        |
+----------------------------------------+------------------------+
```

The job runs with no error but the data read is not proper. It reads in the below manner.

Output:

```
+----------------------------------------+------------------------+
|                                    text|                    time|
+----------------------------------------+------------------------+
|\#Word #This \"\"are acting though.\"\""|                        |
+----------------------------------------+------------------------+
|This is the                             |                        |
|Not so.\",08-11-2016  05:47:00          |                        |
+----------------------------------------+------------------------+
|I'm not sure if I have any left         | 08-11-2016  05:48:00   |
+----------------------------------------+------------------------+
|\bob day is an honest  person           | 08-11-2016  05:49:00   |
|\"\"a loss to the senate\"\"\""         |                        |
+----------------------------------------+------------------------+
```

Struck with this as the line is split into two rows after the double quote and also see few "\". Timestamp also moved.

Comment: can you give a sample data. I am not able to reproduce the same issue. I tried inserting new lines in a cell and it works for me when multiline is True. From what i understand, '\' maybe the issue here.

Comment: @mayankagrawal yes the extra '\' are being added to the output data. The input has only double quotes.

Comment: I think setting argument 'escape' to a different value than default '\' might work

Comment: I had similar problem and found a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53818894/is-there-any-option-to-preserve-line-breaks-within-quotation-marks-when-reading

Answer (score 1):

According to this [link](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/425), you should set the `wholeFile` option to `True` to escape newlines between the character specified by `escape`. However it looks like you have not escaped the text containing newlines so this will probably not work. You should perhaps reformat the source in such a way that text containing newlines is quoted.

Comment: Thanks @ags29 adding ("escape",'\n') and ("wholeFile","True") solved the problem some extent. The third record is now coming properly. Problem still persists with records like first one.