# Is there any option to preserve line breaks within quotation marks when reading multiline CSV files in Spark?

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark, import-from-csv

I have some CSV file with line break within quotation marks in third line (first line is CSV header).

*data/testdata.csv*

```
"id", "description"
"1", "some description"
"2", "other description with line
break"
```

Regardless if its correct CSV or not, I must parse it into valid records. That's what I tried

```java
public class Main2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
            .master("local[4]")
            .getOrCreate();
        Dataset<Row> rows = spark
            .read()
            .format("csv")
            .option("header", "true")
            .load("data/testdata.csv");

        rows
            .foreach(row -> System.out.println(row));
    }
}
```

And the output is like below:

```
[1, "some description"]
[2, "other description with line]
[break",null]
```

As you can see, Spark treats `break"` as a new record and fills missing columns with null. The question is: is there any option to Spark's CSV parser that allows such line breaks?

I tried the code below ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408558/how-to-handle-multi-line-rows-in-spark)) but it doesn't work

```java
Dataset<Row> rows = spark.read()
    .option("parserLib", "univocity")
    .option("multiLine", "true")
    .csv("data/testdata.csv");
```

Comment: yes.. what you observed is correct. though the option says multiline, spark will fill the columns as null..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this article](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/12627/how-to-parse-a-file-with-newline-character-escaped.html) since spark 2.2.0 there is possibility for parsing multiline csv files. In my case these settings do the job:

```
sparkSession
    .read()
    .option("sep", ";")
    .option("quote", "\"")
    .option("multiLine", "true")
    .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", true)
    .csv(path.toString());
```